# Make boost::function take a reference to my function object

Tags: c++, boost, struct, boost-function

I want to pass a struct implementing `operator()` in to a function that accepts `boost::function`. This struct keeps track of the number of times it's been called.

```
struct CallCounter
{
    CallCounter() : count( 0 ) {}
    void operator()()
    {
        // do stuff
        cout << "count is at " << count << endl;
        ++count;
    }

    int count;
};
```

However, when I try to access `count` after passing it to another function, `count` is still at 0.

```
void callNTimes( int n, boost::function<void()> func )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; ++i )
        func();
}

int main()
{
    CallCounter counter;
    callNTimes( 20, counter );

    cout << counter.count << endl; // prints 0
    return 0;
}
```

Even though while `counter` is being called, it's printing out the correct `count`. I understand that `boost::function` is making a copy of my `struct counter`. Is there a way to pass it by reference so that afterwards, `count` is the right number?

Comment: I did not read the question thoroughly enough :(

Comment: @MooingDuck, you should post it as an answer. I prefer template instead. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The boost `function` stuff takes variables by value by default, much like normal functions.  If you want the function to use a *reference* to your `CallCounter`, you have to tell it that explicitly:

```
callNTimes( 20, boost::ref(counter) );
```

See it here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5843b6dde685b569

There also exists a `boost::cref` if you want a constant reference, but no `boost::rref` (which would be nearly identical to a value, but single use.  `function` is multi-use, so no moves).  Additionally, as of C++11, all of this is also in the `std` namespace.

In addition, Jefffrey's suggestion is generally considered a better way to code this sort of thing, if possible.  It can have a negative impact on compile times though.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are using `boost::function`. It's actually not necessary here, you can just use templates and pass the functor by reference:

```
template<typename Functor>
void callNTimes( int n, Functor& func )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; ++i )
        func();
}
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d5e813b73fe4cd7d)

Comment: I think I'd recommend `Functor&&` in C++11, or a `const Functor&`/`Functor&` pair in C++03.

Comment: In this particular case between `const Functor&` and `Functor&` only the latter will work, and `Functor&&` doesn't really change much; but as a general idea, I definitely second the suggestion.